# How to retrieve array values in c from another function

Tags: arrays, c

Here's my code:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int func(int a[]);

int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    a[] = func(a);
```

What changes should I make on the above line to get the new values in the array ?

```
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}

int func(int a[])
{
    for (i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        a[i] = a[i] + 1;
    }
    return a;
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: `func` is already modifying the passed array. So there is no need to return or assign anything.

Comment: yeah. in the `func` function i have modified the values and now i want to pass the new values to the `main` function

Comment: `a[]=func(a);` -> `func(a);`

Comment: @RawNewton `a` is already having the "new" values in `main` after `func` is run.

Comment: You don't need to return any value from the function `func`. You are already passing the pointer of the array as a parameter.

Comment: @klutt that would only call the function

Comment: so how do i print now in the main function? because i'm not getting the updated value

Comment: Also, I'm not using different names in the argument so don't get confused with that.

Comment: @RawNewton Why are you assuming that it should not work without even trying?

Comment: Furthermore. If you have `int a[5] = {1,2,3,4,5};` as in your code, there's NOTHING that could follow either `a=` or `a[]=` that would compile

Comment: sorry. I tried using `return array` in the `func` function which was giving me the error.

Answer (score 2):

When you pass an array as an argument of a function, it is not a copy, in fact that argument  decays to a pointer to the first element of the passed array, using `int func(int a[]);` is basically the same as using `int func(int *a);`, any changes made to the array inside the function will be permanent.

> *What changes should I make on the above line to get the new values in the array?*

Given the above explanation, your function doesn't need to return `a`:

```
void func(int a[]) // as no return is needed, the return type should be void
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        a[i] = a[i] + 1;
    }
    // no need to return a, it's permanently changed already
}
```

Consequently the assignment to `a` in `main` needs to be replaced by a simple function call:

```
int main()
{
    int a[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};

    func(a); //call the function

    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        printf("%d ", a[i]);
    }
}
```

The output will be:

```
2 3 4 5 6
```

Comment: Thanks got it now. I made mistake by returning the array.

Comment: @RawNewton, correct, there is no need to return the array